# dynamic handler creation in tornado web app

Tags: python, tornado

I am looking for a way by which I can create handlers based on configuration. Configuration will contain http verb, authorized user list and logic to execute for the given handler and verb combination.

Here I want to avoid each developers time in writing a class derived from RequestHandler and let them focus on logic to pull data. As rest of the code will be common for authentication, response generation they can just specify what type of request they are expecting like GET or POST and who are the authorized users to send such request.

Is there any out of the box option available in tornado to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a default handler which can server any request. Although this will not create multiple tornado handlers but just 1 which will work based on regex to capture requests and act accordingly. Below is the sample of how I achieved it:

```
class DefaultHandler( tornado.web.RequestHandler ):
    def get( self ):
        path = self.request.path
        parameters = self.request.arguments
        #action to perform based on path and parameters

handlers = [ ( r'/.*', DefaultHandler), ]
app = tornado.web.Application( handlers )
```